# displaying database text in edittext that corresponds to the row in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-edittext

I have a problem with pulling data from database to insert it into edittext before new text is being entered. I know that there is possibility in xml edittext android:text but I am worried that more coding will be involved.
Basically I want that the user, upon edittext (edit corresponding row) leave the previously entered value or change it to new value.
 I can post my files if necessary.
Kind regards for your help.

This is my Diary file which updates rows with corresponding EditText fields:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;
public class Diary extends Activity {
EditText titleET1;
EditText titleET2;
EditText titleET3;
EditText titleET4;
EditText titleET5;
EditText titleET6;
EditText titleET7;
EditText titleET8;
EditText titleET9;
EditText titleET10;
EditText titleET11;
EditText titleET12;
EditText titleET13;
EditText titleET14;
EditText titleET15;
EditText titleET16;
EditText titleET17;
EditText titleET18;
EditText titleET19;
EditText titleET20;
EditText titleET21;
EditText titleET22;
EditText titleET23;
EditText titleET24;
EditText titleET25;
EditText titleET26;
EditText titleET27;
EditText titleET28;
EditText titleET29;
EditText titleET30;
EditText titleET31;
EditText titleET32;
EditText titleET33;
EditText titleET34;
EditText titleET35;
EditText titleET36;
EditText titleET37;
EditText titleET38;
EditText titleET39;
EditText titleET40;
EditText titleET41;
EditText titleET42;
EditText titleET43;
EditText titleET44;
EditText titleET45;
EditText titleET46;
EditText titleET47;
EditText titleET48;

Button submitBT;
MyDB dba;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {





    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diary);
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    titleET1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary1);
    titleET2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary2);
    titleET3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary3);
    titleET4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary4);
    titleET5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary5);
    titleET6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary6);
    titleET7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary7);
    titleET8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary8);
    titleET9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary9);
    titleET10 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary10);
    titleET11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary11);
    titleET12 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary12);
    titleET13 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary13);
    titleET14 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary14);
    titleET15 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary15);
    titleET16 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary16);
    titleET17 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary17);
    titleET18 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary18);
    titleET19 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary19);
    titleET20 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary20);
    titleET21 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary21);
    titleET22 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary22);
    titleET23 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary23);
    titleET24 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary24);
    titleET25 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary25);
    titleET26 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary26);
    titleET27 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary27);
    titleET28 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary28);
    titleET29 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary29);
    titleET30 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary30);
    titleET31 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary31);
    titleET32 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary32);
    titleET33 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary33);
    titleET34 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary34);
    titleET35 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary35);
    titleET36 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary36);
    titleET37 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary37);
    titleET38 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary38);
    titleET39 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary39);
    titleET40 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary40);
    titleET41 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary41);
    titleET42 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary42);
    titleET43 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary43);
    titleET44 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary44);
    titleET45 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary45);
    titleET46 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary46);
    titleET47 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary47);
    titleET48 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary48);



    submitBT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                saveItToDB();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    });
}



public void saveItToDB() {
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET1.getText().toString(), 1);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET2.getText().toString(), 2);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET3.getText().toString(), 3);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET4.getText().toString(), 4);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET5.getText().toString(), 5);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET6.getText().toString(), 6);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET7.getText().toString(), 7);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET8.getText().toString(), 8);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET9.getText().toString(), 9);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET10.getText().toString(), 10);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET11.getText().toString(), 11);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET12.getText().toString(), 12);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET13.getText().toString(), 13);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET14.getText().toString(), 14);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET15.getText().toString(), 15);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET16.getText().toString(), 16);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET17.getText().toString(), 17);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET18.getText().toString(), 18);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET19.getText().toString(), 19);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET20.getText().toString(), 20);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET21.getText().toString(), 21);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET22.getText().toString(), 22);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET23.getText().toString(), 23);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET24.getText().toString(), 24);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET25.getText().toString(), 25);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET26.getText().toString(), 26);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET27.getText().toString(), 27);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET28.getText().toString(), 28);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET29.getText().toString(), 29);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET30.getText().toString(), 30);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET31.getText().toString(), 31);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET32.getText().toString(), 32);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET33.getText().toString(), 33);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET34.getText().toString(), 34);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET35.getText().toString(), 35);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET36.getText().toString(), 36);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET37.getText().toString(), 37);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET38.getText().toString(), 38);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET39.getText().toString(), 39);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET40.getText().toString(), 40);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET41.getText().toString(), 41);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET42.getText().toString(), 42);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET43.getText().toString(), 43);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET44.getText().toString(), 44);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET45.getText().toString(), 45);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET46.getText().toString(), 46);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET47.getText().toString(), 47);
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET48.getText().toString(), 48);

    dba.close();
    titleET1.setText("");

    titleET2.setText("");
    titleET3.setText("");
    titleET4.setText("");
    titleET5.setText("");
    titleET6.setText("");
    titleET7.setText("");
    titleET8.setText("");
    titleET9.setText("");
    titleET10.setText("");
    titleET11.setText("");
    titleET12.setText("");
    titleET13.setText("");
    titleET14.setText("");
    titleET15.setText("");
    titleET16.setText("");
    titleET17.setText("");
    titleET18.setText("");
    titleET19.setText("");
    titleET20.setText("");
    titleET21.setText("");
    titleET22.setText("");
    titleET23.setText("");
    titleET24.setText("");
    titleET25.setText("");
    titleET26.setText("");
    titleET27.setText("");
    titleET28.setText("");
    titleET29.setText("");
    titleET30.setText("");
    titleET31.setText("");
    titleET32.setText("");
    titleET33.setText("");
    titleET34.setText("");
    titleET35.setText("");
    titleET36.setText("");
    titleET37.setText("");
    titleET38.setText("");
    titleET39.setText("");
    titleET40.setText("");
    titleET41.setText("");
    titleET42.setText("");
    titleET43.setText("");
    titleET44.setText("");
    titleET45.setText("");
    titleET46.setText("");
    titleET47.setText("");
    titleET48.setText("");


    Intent i = new Intent(Diary.this, Monday.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the Back button */
public void visitMonday(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Monday.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

diary.xml is populated with EditText fields.

And here is the file that displays list of rows:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;






public class Monday extends ListActivity {
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;
private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;

    }
    public String title;
    public String content;

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}

private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();
    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Comment: what have u done till now ?

Comment: I will post the code in a moment

Comment: I posted code where I update rows with new entries. I am not sure how I could populate edittext's with values that are already in rows.

Comment: does anybody have an idea how I could implement this functionality?